# preg_replace all digit and asterisk characters except at start of string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

Need to replace all characters in a string except for any that are at the start of a string (or part of a word).

For example input:

```
MSFT *<E07004QY6W>
WOOLWORTHS W1157
GOOGLE*ADWS7924436927
COLES 0829
ROBLOX.COM 888-858-25
7-ELEVEN 2179
COLES EXPRESS 1896
```

result should be:

```
MSFT
WOOLWORTHS
GOOGLE
COLES
ROBLOX.COM
7-ELEVEN
COLES EXPRESS
```

Can php preg_replace achieve this?

Tried so far:

- '/\d+/g' - but it removes ALL digits and nothing else
- '/(*|\d+$)/' - but this doesn't quite work on some, results in "ROBLOX.COM 888-858-"

Comment: Please update the question with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Take a look at this as a beginning:

`([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+).+\n`

https://regex101.com/r/EtgztL/1/

The problem is to match "COLES EXPRESS" without matching "WOOLWORTHS W1157".

Comment: Yes, `preg_replace` could do this with the right regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure this will work for other edge cases, but you can try with this replacement:

```
$txt = preg_replace('~^[^*\s]+(?: \pL+(?!\S))*\K.*~m', '', $txt);
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/0jtTv1/1/)

Explanations:

`^[^*\s]+` takes all that isn't a space or an asterisk at the start of the line.

`(?: \pL+(?!\S))*` and eventually group of letters separated by spaces.

`\K` removes all previous matched characters from the match result.

`.*` takes all the remaining characters that will be replaced.

Answer (score 0):

```
$in = array(
    'MSFT *<E07004QY6W>',
    'WOOLWORTHS W1157',
    'GOOGLE*ADWS7924436927',
    'COLES 0829',
    'ROBLOX.COM 888-858-25',
    '7-ELEVEN 2179',
    'COLES EXPRESS 1896',
);

foreach ($in as $str) {
    echo preg_replace('/[\h*]+[^\h*]+$/', '', $str),"\n";
}
```

**Output:**

```
MSFT
WOOLWORTHS
GOOGLE
COLES
ROBLOX.COM
7-ELEVEN
COLES EXPRESS
```